# Delete uploaded file with formidable

Tags: express, formidable

Hey I am creating image upload functionality in my application using formidable module.It works fine when uploading image but I want to perform some validation on it like checking image type and image size but I'm not getting a way to validate size of image.

I don't want user to upload image more than 1Megabyte.

```
router.post('/upload',function(req,res,next){

var types = ['image/jpeg','image/png'];
var error = true;


var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

form.uploadDir = path.join(__dirname,'../public/images/profile');


form.on('fileBegin',function(name,file){


    var type = types.find(type => type == file.type);

    if(!type){
        throw "Image should be in jpeg or png format.";
    }


});

form.on('file',function(name,file){

    fs.rename(file.path,path.join(form.uploadDir,file.name),function(err){
        if(err) console.log(err);
    });

});

form.on('error',function(err){
    if(err) console.log("Error");
});

form.on('end',function(){
    if(!error) console.log("updated"); 
});


form.parse(req);
});
```

Comment: See [this discussion](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable/issues/324). It's not directly supported by `formidable` (as opposed to, say, [`multer`](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#limits)), but if you check `file.size` in the `fileBegin` handler you may be able to block large uploads.

Comment: I logged file.size inside of fileBegin and I'm getting 0 in return.

Comment: Hmm okay, that's not very useful then. You can perhaps use the [`progress`](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable#progress) event to maintain a count of how much has been actually uploaded, and block the upload when it has reached the 1MB limit.

Comment: Thanks I think multer has more functionality as compare to formidable.